How to use ArgoCD Appset to first deploy some helm charts and finally deploy custom yaml manifests k8s resources
I have the following AppSet I just created for deploying 2 helm charts:
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: main-appset
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  generators:
  - list:
      elements:
        - appName: istio-base
          repoURL: https://istio-release.storage.googleapis.com/charts
          chart: base
          namespace: istio-system
          targetRevision: 1.20.0
        - appName: istiod
          repoURL: https://istio-release.storage.googleapis.com/charts
          chart: istiod
          namespace: istio-system
          targetRevision: 1.20.0
  template:
    # Application Metadata
    metadata:
      name: "{{appName}}-application"
      namespace: argocd
    spec:
      project: default
      source:
        repoURL: "{{repoURL}}"
        chart: "{{chart}}"
        helm:
          releaseName: "{{appName}}"
        targetRevision: "{{targetRevision}}"
      destination:
        server: 'https://kubernetes.default.svc'
        namespace: "{{namespace}}"
      syncPolicy:
        automated:
          prune: true
          selfHeal: true
          allowEmpty: true
        syncOptions:
          - PruneLast=true
          - CreateNamespace=true
          - PrunePropagationPolicy=foreground
        retry:
          limit: 2  

What I want to know is how to continue deploying custom resources defined in manifests once I have my helm charts deployed. Is this possible to do in same AppSet or I need to first create the AppSet wait for apps to deploy and then deploy an additional argocd Application with my custom resources defined in yamls?
